# pyqt5's setPlainText / appendPlainText doesn't show text right away

Tags: python, pyqt5

I use `pyqt5` to practice using the `QplainTextEdit` control. Click `QpushButton` to display the set text or append text in `QplainTextEdit`, but it will not be displayed immediately. You need to click and drag to display it. What is the problem?

Attached (use environment):

```
MacOS 10.13.6
python3.7.6
pycharm
pyqt5.13.2
```

[image]
After clicking the "set text" button
[image]
After clicking the "append text" button
[image]
After clicking and dragging with the mouse
This is all my code：

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPlainTextEdit, QPushButton
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 PlainTextEdit")
        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 400, 300)
        self.plainText = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.plainText.setPlaceholderText("This is some text for our plaintextedit")
        self.btn = QPushButton('set text')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.setText)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton('append text')
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.appendText)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.plainText)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn2)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def setText(self):
        print("set text button click")
        self.plainText.setPlainText('This is set text')

    def appendText(self):
        print("append text button click")
        self.plainText.appendPlainText('This is append text')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: try add `self.plainText.repaint()`

Comment: I ran your code and did not experience the issue (using v 5.9.2) . I wouldn't be surprised if pyqt 5.13 is just a less stable version because it was only recently released. You can install a specific version for instance with `pip install PyQt5==5.9.2`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. @eyllanesc

Comment: pip install PyQt5==5.9.2， When I do it. It work! Thank you very much!  @alec